# pgfdeclareshape: Inherit anchor from other shape under a different name

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to inherit anchors under a different name? Like this:

```
\pgfdeclareshape{baseshape}     
{     
    \anchor{someanchor}{...}     
}     
     
\pgfdeclareshape{subshape}     
{     
    \inheritanchoras[from=baseshape]{someanchor}{differentanchorname}     
}
```

with a fictitious command `inheritanchoras`.

I'm not set on this, so I'm also happy to find a different solution. I have a shape that serves as base for two very similar shapes. These shapes inherit almost everything but swap two anchors (which I currently define manually in both shapes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Define

```
\def\pgf@sh@inheritanchoras[from=#1]#2#3{%
  \edef\pgf@marshal{\global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname
    pgf@anchor@\pgf@sm@shape@name @#3\endcsname=\expandafter\noexpand\csname
    pgf@anchor@#1@#2\endcsname}%
  \pgf@marshal
}
```

and use as

```
\pgf@sh@inheritanchoras[from=baseshape]{someanchor}{differentanchorname}
```

should make `differentanchorname` in your current shape declaration to use `baseshape`'s definition of `someanchor`.

You can of course say

```
\let\inheritanchoras\pgf@sh@inheritanchoras
```

to not have to use the `@`-ridden internal version, though unless you patch `\pgfdeclareshape` (or define your own) for this, this will make `\inheritanchoras` defined outside of `\pgfdeclareshape`, too. (The other macros like `\inheritanchor` are only valid inside `\pgfdeclareshape`.)